# help with error

Tags: c#

I am reading a row from a data table and trying to insert into a database. In the row, some cells/columns doesn't contain a value. So, I am trying to check initially whether the row contains a value or not and then insert into database. Here is my code,

```
string barcode = null;
string itemName = null;
double cost = 0;
double price = 0;
double Stock = 0;
string dept = null;
double tax = 0;

barcode = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);

if (dr[1] != string.Empty || dr[1] != null)
    itemName = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);

if (dr[2] != string.Empty || dr[2] != null)
    cost = Convert.ToDouble(dr[2]);

if (dr[3] != string.Empty || dr[3] != null)
    price = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3]);

Stock = Convert.ToDouble(dr[4]);

if (dr[5] != string.Empty || dr[5] != null)
    dept = Convert.ToString(dr[5]);

if (dr[6] != string.Empty || dr[6] != null)
    tax = Convert.ToDouble(dr[6]);
```

But, I am getting an error:

> possible unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison.

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, post your error.

Second, `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is pretty *win*.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dr[1] != string.Empty || dr[1] != null)
```

will always return `true`, even if the string is empty or null. This is because something cannot be both string.Empty AND null! You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dr[1] != string.Empty || dr[1] != null)
```

You get this error because `dr[1]` etc. returns an object, not a string - you have to cast it to a string or call `ToString()` to do a proper string comparison. Also (see @antisanity's answer) you might just want

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( dr[1].ToString()))
```